# Fineuploader 3.3 CORS upload failed error IE9 IE8

Tags: cors, fine-uploader

I am having having trouble with FineUploader for cross domain (CORS) submission inside of a hidden iframe (i.e. IE 9, 8). For each cross-domain upload request, the image uploads successfully, but the error message displays, with the IE bugger stating:

```
No valid message received from loaded iframe for file id 1
```

In detail now, their [blog](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/) says that:

> All cross-domain iframe-initiated responses must end with the script tag above, and the valid JSON portion MUST include the UUID of the associated file. Note that you must host the iframe.xss.response.js file on an accessible server and reference it in the  tag accordingly. When the contents of your response is returned to the iframe tracked by Fine Uploader, the associated javascript file imported by the script tag above will be executed, and will pass the JSON portion of your response to the uploader via window.postMessage.

Ok, so I implement this as follows:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
                || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']!="XMLHttpRequest")){{
        header("Content-Type: text/html");
        $result['uuid'] = $uploader->gen_uuid();
        echo json_encode($result);
        echo "<script src='http://example.com/js/iframe.xss.response-3.3.0.js'></script>";
    }
```

Now, Fiddler says the response is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 17 Mar 2013 03:26:49 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=VJ3AgTRnMtjAqbxizfXBN3; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 203
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

{"success":true,"uploadName":"_73d05d51b4ab624e3260ef0b289a60bc_NMS_0785.JPG","uuid":"749174c7-e29c-485f-9f6d-cc18d4b5d0fd"}<script src='http://example.com/js/iframe.xss.response-3.3.0.js'></script>
```

And the IE debugger says:

```
 [FineUploader] Processing 1 files or inputs... 
 [FineUploader] Sending upload request for 1 
 [FineUploader] Received iframe load event for CORS upload request (file id 1) 
 [FineUploader] Received the following window message: '{"success":true,"uploadName":"_73d05d51b4ab624e3260ef0b289a60bc_NMS_0785.JPG","uuid":"749174c7-e29c-485f-9f6d-cc18d4b5d0fd"}' 
 [FineUploader] Received the following window message: '{"success":true,"uploadName":"_73d05d51b4ab624e3260ef0b289a60bc_NMS_0785.JPG","uuid":"749174c7-e29c-485f-9f6d-cc18d4b5d0fd"}' 
[FineUploader] No valid message received from loaded iframe for file id 1 
 [FineUploader] iframe loaded
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I'm attempting to fill in for the Fineuploader developer until he returns from Holiday. Are you sure the JS file is serving correctly  from `http://example.com/js/iframe.xss.response-3.3.0.js`? (I assume `example.com` is placeholder text.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed, by looking at the request, that the UUID of the file sent along with the POST request matches the UUID in your response? Most likely, the UUID you are sending in your response is wrong.

Comment: Ray - I am running into this same issue in IE9.  Have a Java server returning the correct response with uuid, along with a valid iframe.css.response.js.  confirmed qquuid being sent in the request matches response json with uuid.  I can privately send you a link to the page that is showing the issue.